# Accessing other parameters than value in a datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datalist

I use a datalist on an input field :

```
<input list='cases_list_data' id='caseList_selector'/>
<datalist id='cases_list_data'>
    <option value='xxx'>1</option>
    <option value='yyy'>2</option>
</datalist>
```

I bind to it an input event :

```
$("#caseList_selector").on('input', function () {
  var val = this.value;
  if($('#cases_list_data option').filter(function(){
    return this.value === val;        
  }).length) {
    alert(this.value);
  }
});
```

this.value returns xxx or yyy .... but I would like to return 1 or 2 (the text between the option tags.
I have tried to put :

```
<option data-id='1' value='xxx'>1</option>
```

But both foloowing tries return undefined :

```
$('option:selected', this).data('id')
$(this).data('id');
```

How could I get something more than only the value of a datalist option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.value` is the value of the `value` attribute of the `select` tag, so to get the text of the selected

```
$("#caseList_selector").on('input', function () {
  var val = this.value;
  var text = "";
  if($('#cases_list_data option').filter(function(){
    if(this.value === val)
    {
       text = $(this).text();
       return true;
    }
    return false;         
  }).length) {
    alert(text);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $("#caseList_selector").on('input', function () {
        var val = this.value;
        var $option = $('#cases_list_data option').filter(function(){
            return this.value === val;
        });
        
        if ($option.length) {
            alert($option.eq(0).text());
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list='cases_list_data' id='caseList_selector'/>
<datalist id='cases_list_data'>
    <option value='xxx'>1</option>
    <option value='yyy'>2</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#caseList_selector").on('input', function (e) {
    var val = this.value;
    var txt = $('#cases_list_data option[value="' + val + '"]').text();
    alert('txt: ' + txt + ' value: ' + val);
  });
});
```

```html
In alternative it's possible to use:

<pre>
$(this.list).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').text()
</pre>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<input list='cases_list_data' id='caseList_selector'/>
<datalist id='cases_list_data'>
    <option value='xxx'>1</option>
    <option value='yyy'>2</option>
</datalist>
```